# Trying to run a bash script Selenium demo on MacOS in zsh, but can't find import

Tags: bash, macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to run a simple demo with Selenium in a bash script on macOS. The script is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source ./selenium.sh

main() {   
 # Open the URL   
 navigate_to 'https://www.google.com'
 # Get the search box   
 local searchBox=$(find_element 'name' 'q')
 # send keys    
 send_keys $searchBox "panda\n"
}
main
```

The error is:
`line 2: ./selenium.sh: No such file or directory`

I installed Selenium and wrote it to the project directory with NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio Code so I have no idea why this script cannot find the file or directory for selenium.sh

I tried running the script from Visual Studio code and I tried running it from a zsh terminal but in both cases the same output appeared. It seems to have trouble finding selenium packages but it shouldn't because I successfully wrote the Selenium Web Driver with NuGet: Add Package

Comment: `.` doesn't refer to the project directory; it refers to the _current working_ directory.

Comment: If you're doing it right, btw, the fact that zsh is your interactive shell has zero impact whatsoever on how the script is run: The `#!/usr/bin/env bash` shebang tells the operating system to start a copy of bash and run the script with that, irrespective of what the parent process is.

Comment: Anyhow -- to see what the current working directory is in any given context, run `pwd`, or expand the variable `$PWD`. If you want to refer to the directory that your script is in, for a script being run by bash, use `${BASH_SOURCE[0]%/*}`; so that means you can use `source "${BASH_SOURCE[0]%/*}"/selenium.sh` to load a `selenium.sh` in the same directory as your script.

Comment: BTW, using a `.sh` extension implies that your `selenium` script library is written to be compatible with all POSIX-family shells. If it's written only for bash it should have a `.bash` extension; if it's written only for zsh it should have a `.zsh` extension, etc (whereas _executables_, like scripts meant to be run instead of sourced, shouldn't have extensions at all).

Comment: That said, in general, what you install with nuget is typically a completely separate matter from what's _in your current directory_. Installation tools generally only promise to put content somewhere on the PATH, not to put it in your working tree. (And if you're dealing with nuget, I'd expect powershell core to be a more natural choice than bash; granted, it's not there out-of-the-box on MacOS, but it's available for installation nonetheless).

Comment: (A separate, somewhat speculative concern; take this with a grain of salt from someone who isn't in the Microsoft ecosystem except occasionally, and is thus at some risk of talking out their arse, _but_: I wouldn't generally expect telling nuget to install selenium on MacOS to actually install Selenium; instead, I would expect it to install a dotnet _wrapper_ for selenium that may require you to have a native copy of selenium installed separately; just as using `pip install selenium` would install a Python control plane for selenium, but not necessarily selenium itself).

Answer (score 0):

NuGet has installed the packages in `~/.nuget/packages` unless you have changed the configuration, therefore

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source ~/.nuget/packages/selenium/selenium.sh

main() {   
 # Open the URL   
 navigate_to 'https://www.google.com'
 # Get the search box   
 local searchBox=$(find_element 'name' 'q')
 # send keys    
 send_keys $searchBox "panda\n"
}
main
```

should work assuming selenium package was installed under that directory and `selenium.sh` exists, does what you think it does, etc.

And as the comment recommends, if you are planning to use selenium outside of VSC, there are better ways.